# Rotation matrices using a change-of-basis approach

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I have worked this out on paper and I'm hoping someone can point out my mistake.

A "look at" matrix is supposed to rotate you so your old $(x,y,z)$ coordinate axes become aligned with a new set of coordinate axes $(newx, newy, newz)$.  Basically a change of basis.

Working in an LH coordinate system, using *row major* matrices, according to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205342%28VS.85%29.aspx), this rotation matrix should be constructed as:

$$
\left[
\matrix
{
newx.x&newy.x&newz.x \\
newx.y&newy.y&newz.y \\
newx.z&newy.z&newz.z

}
\right]
$$

(Note I have left off the final translation row from the article - assuming we are working with 3x3 matrices here.)

Assume I pass in

- $eye=(0,0,0)$ (so there is no translation, only rotation of the coordinate axes),
- $at=(0,0,1)$ (so we are "looking down the +z axis"),
- $up=(\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0)$ (so we basically are doing a 30 degree rotation about the z-axis).

Compute

- $newz=(0,0,1)$,
- $newx=( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0 )$,
- $newy=(\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0)$

So far we are on track:  the $newz$ vector points in the same direction it did before, $newx$ is 30 degrees rotated about the z-axis, and $newy$ is 30 degrees rotated about the z-axis.

Form the rotation matrix:

$$
\left[
\matrix
{
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{-1}{2}       & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0 \\
0                  & 0                  & 1

}
\right]
$$

(I tested this on a computer and this is exactly the matrix that the library will form, with these inputs),

Yet premultiply with a sample vector like $ \left[ \matrix{1&0&0} \right] $, and get $ \left[ \matrix{ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{-1}{2}& 0 } \right] $ as the result, meaning $ \left[ \matrix{1&0&0} \right] $ lands rotated *negative* 30 degrees, not as expected.

If you transpose this rotation matrix though, you will get the expected answer of $ \left[ \matrix{ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{1}{2}& 0 } \right] $.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: If you have a rotation matrix $J(\theta)$ that rotates by an angle of $\theta$, its transpose rotates by an angle of $-\theta$, due to the matrices being orthogonal. Another way to put it: if $J$ rotates stuff anticlockwise, its transpose rotates things clockwise.

Comment: I always found change of basis extremely confusing myself, and even now I'm not convinced I know what the accepted convention is. The problem is this: is the universe changing, or are you only changing your perspective on the universe?

Comment: [Very related...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29012)

Comment: ... in that vein, with regards to "I tested this on a computer and this is exactly the matrix that the library will form, with these inputs", is your library intended for rotating row vectors or column vectors?

Comment: @Qiaochu: covariant versus contravariant.

Comment: @Willie: yes, it's easy to say that, but sometimes it isn't clear to me what is a covariant variable and what is a contravariant variable. I thought I could tell, and then I took a course on special relativity, which proved to me that I actually couldn't...

Comment: @Qiaochu: the way I like to explain it to linear algebra students is via measurement (basically linear functionals, but not in so scary words). First you chose some fundamental _rulers_. Things you directly measure with the rulers are contravariant (you can demonstrate this in a classroom directly). Things you measure by comparing against a contravariant object is covariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I get it.  This is an *unrotation* matrix.  The "look at" matrix *unrotates* things to align with the coordinate axes (ie its an inverse of the rotation matrix that would produce that rotation).